# Android - showing content on button click

Tags: android

I am creating an android application for an event and one of the needs is to show a table of events. The problem is I want to be able to show event content on a button click. The events table I was given is pretty complicated because during the speaker panels there are 5 events going on at the same time. I thought a good way to show this could be similar to in HTML/javascript how you can have a tile view and when you click it you show a hidden Div.

Is there anyway to get this kind of effect in android? I want there to be a label of some sort that spans the parent and I can click it and content will populate underneath it. Any ideas?

Comment: may be you can try the setVisibility property of the object to be hidden and displayed on button click

Comment: Try [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)   
There are a few good tutorials [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) and [here](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-expandable-list-view-example/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it through either a `ListView` or `TableLayout` or `GridView` by adding items dynamically

Comment: Thanks for accepting. It will be good if you can explain how do you implement this. It will be useful for others.